# split array value by index in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, split

I have two arrays

one is $array which consist post data response ,

another is $imagearray which consist only image values,

Here my output, $array have post value

```
array(4) {
["selected"]=> string(4) "test" 
["priority"]=> string(1) "1" 
["matter_title"]=> string(3) "wet" 
["matter_description"]=> string(3) "wet"
}
```

second array have only image value,

```
array(1) {
[0]=> array(3) { 
[0]=> "3.png" 
[1]=> "4.png" 
[2]=> "2.png"
   } 
}
```

for more understanding :

sequence is  that

```
array([0]=[0]=image1,[1]=title1,[2]=des1)
array([1]=[0]=image2,[1]=title2,[2]=des2)
```

for that I applied

```
$a = array($matterarray);   //call image array value
$b = array($array);    //call post value

$d = array_map(null, $a, $b);  //map both value
print_r($d);
```

I got  wrong output. please help me.

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1.png [1] => 3.png [2] => 1.png ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => one [1] => two )) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [0] => three [1] => four )
[2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => tres ) )
```

Comment: Why does your array keys go [0][1][2][1] instead of [0][1][2][3]?

Comment: because i used array_chunk function for chunk post value into chunk @MikeBergerUS

Comment: Sir, I edit my post please verify it. Can you give your suggestion? @MikeBergerUS

Comment: Question is unclear...

Comment: I don't understand how you want to map the data between your two arrays.

Comment: please refer my output.. I want to make array like array([0]=[0]=image1,[1]=title1,[2]=des1) array([1]=[0]=image2,[1]=title2,[2]=des2) from my two arrays now you got it? @MikeBergerUS

Comment: There is two array which have post response or second have only image value ok now I wan this kind of output array([0]=[0]=image1,[1]=title1,[2]=des1)
array([1]=[0]=image2,[1]=title2,[2]=des2) @ShubhamAgrawal

Comment: hey can you use variable name instead of array, because we are not getting your mapping at all. Explain your question as you are telling to a noobie.

Comment: The question is still unclear. It contains invalid syntax like `array([0]=[0]=image1,[1]=title1,[2]=des1)`: that does not make sense. It is also a miracle you get `one` and `two` in your output, when that does not occur at all in your input. Maybe it is easier if you just provide the *desired* output for your sample input.